# How to embed image into HTML to be displayed in UIWebview

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview, mime

I am looking at sending myself some HTML from my server, I would like to know the best way to add image data into the HTML so that when I display the HTML in a UIWebview it displays like a normal webpage.

Their are two prerequisites 
1, I do not want to store the images in the devices bundle
2, I don't want to have links to images hosted else where

I would like to know what formatting I need to use to (I.e. mime encoding etc) in order to read/display it in my UIWebview.

So if you old please give me some pointers on how to achieve this it would be very helpful as m just not 100% sure on where to begin and am finding examples few and far between.

Comment: What do you mean you don't want the images hosted elsewhere? You want to download them, store them, then display them?

Comment: I have the images on my server stored, but I am running a service that will pull this image from the server convert it to mime encoded data or something like that, effectivly I dont want to use an <img src="some link to image"> type link, I would like to embed the image in the html or something similar so I have. So in essence the data being sent has all of the informaiton nessacery to display on the users device, however that might be done iom not quite sure yet.

Comment: Ah, so you want to base64 encode the image or something, like this?

<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />

Comment: yep.. that sounds about right, my one question after that would be this - when i put something like that into html and then try to display in UIWebView will UIWebView know what to do with it?

If not then what do I need to consider when writing my ios code to handle something like this.

Comment: WebKit should be able to handle that directly :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36259/discussion-between-powerj1984-and-hurknburks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've got a base64 encoded image just use it directly in an image tag like this:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO 9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
```